# Is there a possibility to store the output of two lists in seperate values in a list?

Tags: python, list

[image]

I have the following code:

```
import os
import glob
directory = r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\attachments'

files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.*')))
print(files)
```

Then I extract the text values of these pdfs:

```
lines = []

for file in files:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            for line in text.split('\n'):
                print(line)
```

My output is accurate but not in a list with two values..

How can I store the output of the list values in one list so I can slice through the list?

Comment: Do you want to all value in your declared `lines=[]`?

Comment: I would like to have the total output of one file in one item of the list. And then the second file in the second item of the list.

Comment: That means you're seeking the line according to page number like `first page, first line` , `second page, second line` ,  `n page, n line`. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do `lines.append(line)` instead of the `print`

If you need a list for each page you can do:

```
files_data = []

for file in files:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        lines = []
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            for line in text.split('\n'):
                lines.append(line)
        files_data.append(lines)
```

You will have a nested list for each file on `files_data`

Comment: Thanks Joac, however I would like to have the total output of one file in one item of the list. Now I have only one line in the first item print(lines[0]).

Answer (score 0):

You can append your line to `lines` list.

```
lines = []

for file in files:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            for line in text.split('\n'):
                lines.append(line)
```

You also can compress these code in single line

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
   lines.append(line)
```

Compress code

```
lines=[ line for line in text.split('\n')]
```

Comment: Thanks Rex, however I would like to have the total output of one file in one item of the list. Now I have only one line in the first item print(lines[0]).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list for each file, and append the list into the `lines` list:

```
lines = []

for file in files:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        lines.append([line for page in pdf.pages for line in page.extract_text().split('\n')])
```